# Svelte and Bootstrap-table events handlers lost

Tags: svelte, bootstrap-table

i am trying to integrate bootstrap-table with svelte, the effects are applied to the table but the on:click handlers are removed, as far as i understand bootstrap-table is destroying the table and recreating it, therefore all the event handlers get lost, is there a way around this?

Here is an example:

```
<script>

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';    
    let users=[{id:1,name:"Adam",age:30},{id:2,name:"David",age:28}];
    
        const delete_user = (id)=>{
            users = users.filter((user) => user.id !== id);     
          }    

        onMount(async () => {
          jQuery('#table').bootstrapTable(); 
        });
    
    </script>

      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped m-4" id="table"  data-search="true" >
        <thead>
            <tr><th  data-sortable="true" >Name</th>
              <th data-sortable="true">Age</th>
              <th >Delete</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {#each users as user}
            <tr>
            <td>{user.name}</td><td>{user.age}</td>
            <td><button on:click={() => delete_user(user.id)} >Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            {/each}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In this example the delete_user is not called anymore when applying bootstrapTable();

Here is a link to try it out, if you press delete before the boostrap-table is applied it works after that it does not work anymore:

https://svelte.dev/repl/01aeb031bd8046f8b2d161ead0bedf89?version=3.48.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow of operations:

1. Svelte is creating the table html and writing it to the page
2. You're then having bootstrap-table operate on this HTML table,
3. Bootstrap-table is replacing the original HTML with it's own, and it's own events.

This mishmash of who is doing what is, as you pointed out, causing you problems.

You'd be better served by by defining the columns and data all in JS when creating the bootstrap-table.

You can pass the users variable directly to bootstrap-table via the data option:
https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#data

For your column with a button, see the formatter column option:
https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/column-options/#formatter

You could define your own html and events in the "formatter" for a column, and in event there make your call to 'delete_user' when the button is clicked.

This fills a little icky and "outside of Svelte", but you're calling in JQuery functions so it comes with the territory.